# Add a file to folder from nuget package not work in UWP

Tags: uwp, xamarin.forms, nuget, nuget-package, xamarin.uwp

I've create a Nuspec file to build my nuget package for a control to Xamarin.Forms.

I want add a .ttf file into **Assets/Fonts** I've been able to add it using:

```xml
<file src="ButtonCircle\ButtonCircle.FormsPlugin.UWP\Assets\Fonts\MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf" target="content\Assets\Fonts" />
```

but only added to PCL, Android and iOS projects, it's not possible to add to the UWP project.

[image: see the project solution explorer using this control]

I'm using Nuget 2.8.1

How can I add this file to UWP project?

Comment: First of all, why're you using v2.8.1? Not sure, but I think UWP came lately then that version of Nuget. Have you tried another Nuget version? Latest recommended is v4.1.0. You can find it [here](https://www.nuget.org/downloads).

Comment: I have tried with nuget v4.0 but I have not get any result....

Answer (score 1):

> I've create a Nuspec file to build my nuget package for a control to Xamarin.Forms.
>
> I want add a .ttf file into Assets/Fonts.

NuGet uses target framework references in a variety of places to specifically identify and isolate framework-dependent components of a package. To include platform-specific reference assemblies, add the following to the  element of .nuspec as appropriate for your uwp platform([UAP10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/target-frameworks)).

```
<file src="ButtonCircle\ButtonCircle.FormsPlugin.UWP\Assets\Fonts\MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf" target="content\UAP10\Assets\Fonts\MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf"/>
```

For more, you could refer to [Create cross-platform packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/guides/create-cross-platform-packages).

Comment: I try your way but it can't run.

Comment: Please try the updated answer. [This](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/develop/nuspec/MvvmCross.StarterPack.nuspec) is mvvmcross .nuspec  sample file you could refer to .

Comment: This still does not work, I have not found it to work :(

Answer (score 0):

In extension to @nico-zhu-msft answer; make sure you clear nuget cache on your DEV system before testing newly created packages; or at least increment the version number to force VS to load package from the right source.

Basically, in order to avoid issues related to local caching; delete packages from these directories:-

```
%LocalAppData%\NuGet\Cache
```

and

```
%userprofile%\.nuget\packages\
```

There is a pretty good chance the reason you are not seeing  any change is because VS is still installing from locally cached version (which is the older package without your new changes).

More details : [Cached nuget packages causing you problems?](http://nodogmablog.bryanhogan.net/2016/05/cached-nuget-packages-causing-you-problems/)